# How to make threads and pass variables between scripts?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have`my main_script.py` and a `second_script.py`

I want to grab from a table where users are activated and pass it to my second script to

```
cursor = db.cursor()
sql_select_count = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE activated = 1;"
cursor.execute(sql_select_count)
results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
```

Depending on this i want to start threads of the other script passing one column of the table inside as a parameter **dynamically**.

Is this possible?

EDIT: 
this is my second script

```
    from selenium import webdriver
import pymysql
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "password", "mysql")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql_select_cookie = "SELECT cue_cookie FROM wa_cuentas WHERE cue_id = '%d'" % 1
sql_select_browser = "SELECT cue_url, cue_session_id FROM wa_cuentas where cue_id = '%d'" % 1
def iniciar_browser(cookie):
    try:
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + cookie)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("http://web.whatsapp.com")
        url = driver.command_executor._url
        session_id = driver.session_id
        sql_update = ("UPDATE wa_cuentas SET cue_url='"
                      "" + url + "',cue_session_id='"
                                 "" + session_id + "',cue_online=1 WHERE cue_cookie='" + cookie + "'")
        cursor.execute(sql_update)
        db.commit()
        return driver
    except:
        print("no se pudo arrancar el browser")

def reconectar_browser(cookie):
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql_select_browser)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in results:
            url = row[0]
            session_id = row[1]
        driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=url, desired_capabilities={})
        driver.session_id = session_id
        return driver
    except:
        return iniciar_browser(cookie)
        print("no existia conexion")
        pass
try:
    # seleccionamos los mensajes que aun no fueron enviados
    cursor.execute(sql_select_cookie)
    cookie = cursor.fetchone()
    cookie = cookie[0]
    driver = reconectar_browser(cookie)

except:
    print("no se pudo traer los datos")
db.close()
```

Comment: Well, a thread runs a _function_, not a _script_. Of course the thread function could just do an `execfile` or `subprocess` out to `sys.executable`, or whatever… but usually it's a lot simpler to reorganize your code so that you just run a function defined in the other script (which you already `import`ed). If you can show us an example of what the other script looks like, and what you want to do with it, we could give you a more specific answer.

Comment: yes, you can use  multiprocessing — Process-based parallelism , Using a pool of workers https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Comment: in my case i want to pass the id from which the query statement will execute

Comment: i'm still new at python i've come from the java world ! so any help is apretiated (english is not my first language)